How biased is $(x_i x_j)_{i,j}$, $x_i\in \mathbb{F}_2$?
Let $N = \frac{n (n-1)}{2}$. Let $V$ be the $N$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ consisting of tuples $(x_{(i,j)})_{1\leq i <j \leq n}$, $x_{(i,j)}\in \mathbb{F}_2$. Let $S$ be the set of all elements of the form $(x_i x_j)_{1\leq i <j \leq n}$ for some $x_i \in \mathbb{F}_2$.
It is easy to see that $S$ generates $V$. Is there a non-trivial upper bound for the size of the intersection $S\cap H$ of $S$ with an arbitrary hyperplane $H$?

You want bounds that are independent of $H$, right? if so, you're asking about a nontrivial upper bound for $u_n=\sup_H |S\cap H|$, right? (a trivial upper bound being $2^n-1$)

You define $N$ in terms of $n$, and then consider an $M$-dimensional space of tuples indexed by pairs $(i, j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le N$.  Is it supposed to be an $N$-dimensional space of tuples indexed by pairs $(i, j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$?

Isn't $S$ in bijection with $\mathbb F_2^N$ (or $\mathbb F_2^n$ if LSpice is right) and the inverse image of the hyperplane $H$ is just the solution set of a polynomial of degree $2$, so you're looking for a bound for the number of solutions of such a polynomial (assuming not every point is a solution)?

In this case the upper bound is $(3/4)2^{N}$ by some classical induction argument.

@YCor Yes, exactly.

@LSpice Yes - I must have been very tired, sorry.

@WillSawin Yes, my question is a special case of yours: no linear or diagonal terms (and then of course the condition that not every point is a solution gets fulfilled easily).

@WillSawin You are right that that bound is easy, by induction - and, without further conditions, one cannot do better for any $n$. Thanks!

@WillSawin The induction seems to run smoothly if one states the problem in terms of a class of polynomials broader than mine and smaller than yours: consider quadratic polynomials in $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ with no terms $x_i^2$ (but with linear terms allowed).

Over $\mathbb F_q$, in a sense, the statement is about polynomials modulo $x_1^{q}-x_1,\dots, x_n^q-x_n$. These all have a unique lift that has degree $<q$ in each variable, and that lift allows for a clean induction proof without working modulo anything. For this problem allowing linear and quadratic terms are morally the same as they give the same function.

One can also apply Warning's second theorem to the polynomial $1-f$, but this is just reversing the steps in a proof (I'm not sure if it's the original one) of Warning's second theorem.
